# how to schedule for every 30 seconds with sidekiq-scheduler

Tags: ruby-on-rails, scheduler, sidekiq, ruby-on-rails-4.1

I am working on ROR application.
i have a functionality requirement, where i have to call a method for 
every 30 seconds using sidekiq

and i am using these gems

```
# sidekiq
gem 'sidekiq', '~> 3.3.0'
# sidekiq scheduler
gem 'sidekiq-scheduler', '~> 2.0'
```

here is my scheduler.yml file code.

```
perform:
  every: ["30s"]
  class: Aggregator
  queue: aggregation
  description: "This job will create Aggregate data."
```

here is my Aggregator class which inside the Workers folder.

```
class Aggregator
  include Sidekiq::Worker
  sidekiq_options :backtrace => 5, :retry => false

  def perform
    end_time = time - (time.sec%30).seconds
    puts "ROUNDING TO 30 SEC"
    puts end_time    
   Session.create_aggregate_data(end_time)
  end
end
```

when i am checking the sidekiq logs it's not hitting the perform method. but the Aggregator class is getting called

here are the logs..

```
2016-07-27T10:19:59.436Z 15117 TID-1qjnlu INFO: queueing Aggregator (perform)
2016-07-27T10:20:29.641Z 15117 TID-1qjnlu INFO: queueing Aggregator (perform)
2016-07-27T10:20:59.836Z 15117 TID-1qjnlu INFO: queueing Aggregator (perform)
2016-07-27T10:21:30.009Z 15117 TID-1qjnlu INFO: queueing Aggregator (perform)
2016-07-27T10:22:00.204Z 15117 TID-1qjnlu INFO: queueing Aggregator (perform)
2016-07-27T10:22:30.507Z 15117 TID-1qjnlu INFO: queueing Aggregator (perform)
2016-07-27T10:23:00.509Z 15117 TID-1qjnlu INFO: queueing Aggregator (perform)
2016-07-27T10:23:30.760Z 15117 TID-1qjnlu INFO: queueing Aggregator (perform)
2016-07-27T10:24:01.068Z 15117 TID-1qjnlu INFO: queueing Aggregator (perform)
```

Comment: So the jobs are being queued but they are not being processed. Silly question: have you started sidekiq? `bundle exec sidekiq` ?

Comment: thanks for responding.. @MrWillihog.
 these logs are coming, when I ran the 'sidekiq' command

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to set queue to default if you didn't configure non-default queues

```
queue: default
```

Comment: Nope, Workers don't need to end in Worker, that's just the naming convention.